# Why AdMob is not showing any ads in my Android app(there are no errors in the code)?

Tags: android, admob, integration

I'm trying really hard to display ads in Android apps. I searched for so many AdMob integration tutorials on the web, but none worked for me. Here are complete details -

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2 on Windows 7

Android SDK Tools Version 24.0.2

Android Support Repository Rev. 16

Android Support Library Rev. 22.2.1

Google Play Services Rev. 32
Google Repository Rev. 32

I've tried so many methods  but none worked for me. Here is my code

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.virender.myapplication;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final String TOAST_TEXT = "Test ads are being shown. ";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);

// Request for Ads
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

// Add a test device to show Test Ads
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB")
.build();

// Load ads into Banner Ads
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Toasts the test ad message on the screen. 
Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

int id = item.getItemId();

if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.virender.adraj" >

<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity
android:name=".MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity> <!-- Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
<activity
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.virender.adraj"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- view for AdMob Banner Ad -->
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>
```

** Here is what my logcat produces **

```
11-15 10:13:29.116    6558-6558/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
11-15 10:13:30.585    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged
11-15 10:13:30.585    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13714: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onWindowSystemUiVisibilityChanged (I)V
11-15 10:13:30.585    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0008
11-15 10:13:31.075    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
11-15 10:13:31.075    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 13710: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
11-15 10:13:31.075    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
11-15 10:13:31.105    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
11-15 10:13:31.105    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 573: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
11-15 10:13:31.115    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-15 10:13:31.165    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
11-15 10:13:31.165    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 595: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
11-15 10:13:31.165    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
11-15 10:13:31.475    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.app.Notification$Builder.setPriority, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a
11-15 10:13:31.475    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 237: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setPriority (I)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
11-15 10:13:31.485    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0035
11-15 10:13:31.545    6558-6563/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 214K, 5% free 7081K/7431K, paused 5ms+8ms
11-15 10:13:31.555    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x00ce at 0x3f in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.a
11-15 10:13:31.585    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
11-15 10:13:31.655    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
11-15 10:13:31.855    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
11-15 10:13:32.675    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj D/gralloc_goldfish﹕ Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-15 10:13:33.655    6558-6567/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 11
11-15 10:13:33.655    6558-6567/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 12
11-15 10:13:33.665    6558-6567/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 13
11-15 10:13:33.665    6558-6567/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 14
11-15 10:13:33.675    6558-6567/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 15
11-15 10:13:33.675    6558-6567/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 16
11-15 10:13:33.675    6558-6567/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 17
11-15 10:13:33.795    6558-6567/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 18
11-15 10:13:34.108    6558-6594/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads-1257843649.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
11-15 10:13:34.305    6558-6594/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END 'ads-1257843649.jar' (success) ---
11-15 10:13:34.305    6558-6594/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep '/data/data/com.example.virender.adraj/cache/ads-1257843649.jar': unzip in 24ms, rewrite 199ms
11-15 10:13:35.646    6558-6563/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 285K, 6% free 7246K/7687K, paused 6ms+5ms
11-15 10:13:35.675    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj D/webviewglue﹕ nativeDestroy view: 0x2febc8
11-15 10:13:36.165    6558-6642/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.net.ConnectivityManager.isActiveNetworkMetered, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.fv.<init>
11-15 10:13:36.165    6558-6642/com.example.virender.adraj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1110: Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;.isActiveNetworkMetered ()Z
11-15 10:13:36.165    6558-6642/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x00d9
11-15 10:13:36.355    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.internal.gu.evaluateJavascript
11-15 10:13:36.355    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 14098: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.evaluateJavascript (Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/webkit/ValueCallback;)V
11-15 10:13:36.355    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0016
11-15 10:13:46.366    6558-6605/com.example.virender.adraj W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
11-15 10:13:46.366    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj D/webviewglue﹕ nativeDestroy view: 0x31a598
11-15 10:13:46.536    6558-6558/com.example.virender.adraj W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 0
11-15 10:19:31.346    6558-6563/com.example.virender.adraj D/dalvikvm﹕ `GC_CONCURRENT freed 347K, 7% free 7306K/7815K, paused 40ms+11ms`
```

**Please friends, help me out! I'm really desperate about solving this problem.**

Comment: Sometimes it takes time to load

Comment: It shows "failed  to load ads" in the logcat

Comment: Have you added MobileAds.initalize(); method?

Comment: Try this `ads:adSize="BANNER"` instead of this `ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"`

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid I've already tried ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" , but it didn't work for me

Comment: @AshwinPrasad I tried to add MobileAds.initalize(); method but it is showing the method in red(error)

Comment: Try this `ads:adSize="BANNER"`

Comment: Have you added all the dependencies ?

Comment: @AshwinPrasad please see build.gradle(Module:app) if the required dependencies are there

Comment: Add 
`apply plugin : 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in build.gradle(app)

And add
`classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:3.0.0'` in build.gradle(project)

Comment: from where you copy this key `B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB` is this your device id? if not then you will get it in logcat.

Comment: @AshishKudale B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB is my device id, I saw it in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't register app on admob.
follow this steps.

1. Sign into your [AdMob](https://apps.admob.com) account.
2. Go to Monetize tab.
3. Create the app and choose the appropriate platform.
4. Choose the ad format and give the ad unit a name.
5. After creating unit name it will generate **Ad unit ID** for example ad id will look like this : ca-app-pub-1234567890000000/9874563210.
6. Now copy your id and paste it in **strings.xml** file

like this

```
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-1234567890000000/9874563210</string>
```

in your onCreate() method of activity paste this code.
make sure you avoid clicking on ads. this will not generate test ads this is real ads. don't click on ads every times. it will result into banning of your admob account.

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

you can also refer this link

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/

Comment: I've already created an account on AdMob, I also tried to publish live ads but it didn't work either.

Comment: could you please post the full code of MainActivity, where the code is the posted exactly

Comment: just remove both lines from your code. `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)`
`.addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB")` and try. I think this may work.